# How to simulate large or slow upload to app hosted by vagrant?

Tags: php, jquery, apache, vagrant, virtualbox

I have a input of type=file. I am trying to work on loading bars but since I'm hosting the app on my local system (using vagrant+virtualbox) uploads go too quickly to work with even using 80MB files.

I have not been about to find out how I could simulate a slow or large upload. I was wondering if there's maybe a way to throttle the network speed to the VM?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Virtual Box limit Bandwith on network](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6311413/virtual-box-limit-bandwith-on-network)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another alternative other than limiting bandwidth through your virtual box would be to use Chrome Inspector. You can set throttling on the page you're visiting. For example:

[image: Throttle your connection]

Comment: You, sir, are a life saver :)

Comment: Glad I could help :D Please mark this as the correct answer!